# Spring Cloud Streams - The Following Method Did Not Exist

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We are currently trying to make a SCS application that produces certain messages to a topic, however while running the application we come across the error:

```
The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.setBeanName(Ljava/lang/String;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.3.4.RELEASE/65f92192fc57991d4b135c715be5a506b3153ea1/spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.3.4.RELEASE/65f92192fc57991d4b135c715be5a506b3153ea1/spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory
```

We think there is a compatibility issue with spring-boot and the SCS. We are using spring-boot version: 2.2.2-RELEASE He have changed our version of SCS to Hoxton 2 and back to Hoxton 6, also tried changing our spring-kafka versioning so it contains the method setBeanName. When changing the spring-kafka version we ran into a similar error with a different method. Here are my gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
```

Here is dependency management:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
```

The issue (we think) is that spring-kafka is getting pulled in from somewhere else and is defaulting to the 2.3.4.RELEASE which doesn't contain the setBeanName.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the spring-kafka dependency to `2.3.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` in the application to solve this issue. Tomorrow (07/22/2020), it is going to be released (`2.3.10.RELEASE`), which is going to be pulled in by Spring Boot `2.2.9.RELEASE` (scheduled for 07/23/2020). Therefore, when that Boot release is available, you should update your application to use that (`2.2.9.REELASE`).

Comment: If we aren't able to update our spring-boot, are you aware if there is another work around?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to alleviate our problem by switching to Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE